how to properly loop and print json record in a single line
The code below loops through the records and displays the result vertical one after another.
Here is what i want
I need to print this text in a single line Eg.  Stackoverflow.com is a Programmers Question and Answering Site
import os
import json
my_json = '["Stack", "over" , "flow", ".com", "is a ", "Programmers Question and Answering Site"]'
data = json.loads(my_json)

# for result in data.values():
for result in data:
    print(result)
# Display the result in a single line


print(' '.join(data)).  Your data is inconsistent with its use of spaces.

print(' '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip(), data))) would do what you need, given the spaces you've got tacked on to some of the list elements. It's unclear why you would use the intermediate step with JSON to define a list to begin with though.

Something like json.loads('["a"]') is just interpreting the string (of valid JSON) as a list of entries .. as others note in the comments, you can then connect these together with the .join() method of strings (note the method is actually from the substring you're joining by, not some member of the collection of strings)
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["a"]')
['a']
>>> json.loads('{"key1": "value1", "key2": null}')
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': None}
>>> ":".join(["one", "two", "three"])
'one:two:three'

Together
>>> " ".join(json.loads(my_json))
'Stack over flow .com is a  Programmers Question and Answering Site'

Finally, fixing the poor spacing around some entries and using print() for nicer display too
>>> print(" ".join(s.strip() for s in json.loads(my_json)))
Stack over flow .com is a Programmers Question and Answering Site

(you can keep doing more work inside to massage entries to be how you'd like, but if you find you're putting a lot into one line, consider if it's readable and understandable and how you might make some helper function(s) to do the work for you in a clearer way)
